# what tables are updated after records are imported

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to find out which tables are updated in SQL Server when the batch is run from a front-end application?

Comment: What kind of batch are you talking about?  The query should indicate the tables that are updated, or are there triggers that update other tables?  What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: All i am trying to find out is what tables are touched when something is entered from front end.

Answer (score 0):

Under 'Tools' in SQL Server Management Studio, you can launch the SQL Server Profiler. Connect to your server of choice, then on your next window, use the event selection tab to filter specifics you are looking for. Click run, then fire your process through your app.  This will only grab events that are hitting your databases and sql server and display them in the window, not web calls. Press pause/stop after you fire your process since the profiler can be heavy on the system.  The events will display either TSQL code if it is hardcoded into your app or it will display stored procedure calls.  If you see stored procedures, you can use sp_helptext in SSMS to find out what the stored procedure is doing and what tables it hits.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'mydb')
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('myobject');
```

Unfortunately, you would have to do something ranged against last_user_update to determine whether the batch did anything.  There is nothing, insofar as I know, to derive the transaction information for a batch process, particularly if there are interspersed commits.

Boy, am I hoping I'm wrong ...  LOL

Comment: Heap?  Not sure what you are referring to.  The question was oriented towards identifying which tables were touched during an import.

Comment: A heap is a table with no clustered index on it.  If the table from the poster is a table with no primary key or indexes, your query will return nothing.

Comment: I have never heard that term before.  Thank you.